# Why is my bundle of data not being sent to my other activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to pass some data from one activity to the second activity once the user clicks on the "Place your order button". I want the data to show up on the second activity but is is giving me either null or zero values. Only explanation is that the data being passed through the bundle is not being set, or is not being delivered. I made a global string variable called size and made it equal to xLarge to try and find where this bug is. When I run the program, it returns a null value in the second activity. Does anyone know why? Here is the code with some photos[image]

[image]

### **Activity 1**

```
    package com.example.switchviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText mEdit;
    EditText mEdit2;
    double amount;
    double small;
    double meduium;
    double large;
    int count = 0;
    int numToppings;
    double toppingsTot=0;
    Button next;
    String size ="xLarge";
    double sizePrice;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    Bundle myData = new Bundle();
                    myData.putDouble("price", amount);
                    myData.putDouble("toppings", toppingsTot);
                    myData.putInt("numberOfToppings", numToppings);
                    myData.putDouble("size", sizePrice);
                // Why is this set to null in activity 2?
                    myData.putString("sizePrice", size);
                    int[] myLittleArray = {1, 2, 3, 4,5,6, 7};
                    myData.putIntArray("myIntArray1", myLittleArray);
                    myIntent.putExtras(myData);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,2);
                }




        });
    }
```

### **Activity 2**

```
    package com.example.switchviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    TextView pizza;
    TextView toppings;
    TextView total;
    Button submit;
    Button cancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        pizza = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pizza);
        toppings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toppings);
        total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);

        Intent myLocalIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle myBundle = myLocalIntent.getExtras();

        double amount = myBundle.getDouble("price");
        double toppingsTot = myBundle.getDouble("toppings");
        int numToppings = myBundle.getInt("numberOfToppings");
        double sizePrice = myBundle.getDouble("sizePrice");
        String size = myBundle.getString("size");
        int[] arr1 = myBundle.getIntArray("myIntArray1");

        pizza.setText("Pizza "+ size + " 1x" + Double.toString(sizePrice)+ "    "+ "   "+ Double.toString(sizePrice) );


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

### **Manifest XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.switchviews"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.switchviews.Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is this set to null in activity 2?

Due to key data-type mismatch. sending `sizePrice` as String from first Activity but trying to get as `double` instead of String.
Do it as:

```
double sizePrice = myBundle.getDouble("size");
String size = myBundle.getString("sizePrice"); // return xLarge
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
    myData.putDouble("size", sizePrice); // Why is this set to null in activity 2?
 myData.putString("sizePrice", size);
```

To

```
    myData.putDouble("sizePrice", sizePrice); 
 myData.putString("size", size);
```